# Open a document(.doc,.pdf) using Google doc viewer - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-document-viewer

I'm trying to open a document on server through google docs. 
I can get the path and name of the file on the server.
And then on Button click event I wrote a method to open the file through google document reader.

```
 string path = \\xxx-yyyyy-zzz\DocShare\sample1.doc //path of the file on server
 Response.Redirect("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + path);
```

When I run this code, I'm getting something like below

[image]

Can some one help me to find where did I go wrong? Is there any other method to open any document(ppt, doc, pdf etc) using google document reader.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

What is `\\xxx-yyyyy-zzz\DocShare\sample1.doc` and where it is ?

> A relative url dosen't specify a protocol & domain which makes the
>   browser to assume the document is referd from the same site/domain.

Please verify if you can access the document itself with the relative path. 
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://s3.amazonaws.com/scotchio/First-Node-App.pdf works for me as i can access the pdf. Try using the absolute url of the document

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work most likely because the file is not accessible from the Internet. The google doc previewer needs to be able to access the file in order to display it.